# NativeScript not showing custom fonts

Tags: nativescript-angular

Custom fonts are not showing up on my app.

I did some googling, pretty sure I named everything correctly, font files are in the correct folder. Not too sure what's going on.

This is how I'm using it in app.css:

```
.pontanosans-regular {
    font-family: "PontanoSans", "PontanoSans-Regular";
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

I am then using this class in the other folder/files like so:

```
class="pontanosans-regular"
```

This is what the folders look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per {[NS](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#custom-fonts)}

> Note: In iOS your font file should be named exactly as the font name.
>   If you have any doubt about the original font name, use the Font Book
>   app to get the original font name.

and Pontano Sans name in mac is  having a space between 2 words. So your family name should be like this.

```
font-family: "Pontano Sans", "PontanoSans-Regular";
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running into this issue and the problem I found was that my .ttf file was buggy.  I tried downloading a common webfont and it worked just fine, so some fonts are just buggy.

To fix my issue, I found the original font on a different site.